# How to capture sound in Java?

Tags: java, audio

I'm trying to capture the sound of the PC. I have managed to capture the sound that enters the microphone through `TargetDataLine`, but I cannot find the way to capture the sound that comes out of the speakers.

I've been watching the `mixer` but I have not managed to capture the sound. I would like to know if someone has done it and if you can give me some clue as to where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Although, your question is not really according to the "rules", here is a code snippet:

```
private byte[] record() throws LineUnavailableException {
    AudioFormat format = AudioUtil.getAudioFormat(audioConf);
    DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);

    // Checks if system supports the data line
    if (!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(info)) {
        LOGGER.error("Line not supported");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    microphone = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
    microphone.open(format);
    microphone.start();

    LOGGER.info("Listening, tap enter to stop ...");

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int numBytesRead;
    byte[] data = new byte[microphone.getBufferSize() / 5];

    // Begin audio capture.
    microphone.start();

    // Here, stopped is a global boolean set by another thread.
    while (!stopped) {
        // Read the next chunk of data from the TargetDataLine.
        numBytesRead = microphone.read(data, 0, data.length);
        // Save this chunk of data.
        byteArrayOutputStream.write(data, 0, numBytesRead);
    }

    return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

Get more info from here:
https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine&method=read

Comment: that way I can read the sound coming from the microphone but not the one that comes out through the speakers, I've already tried that and I have not found a way to modify it to obtain the sound that comes out of the speakers